# url rewrite changing automatically, how to permanently fix this?

Tags: magento-1.9, category, cms, url-rewrite

I have added links to my cms pages in menu bar(about-us, contact-us, gallery).

And created url rewrite(type=custom) with url rewrite management option in magento admin panel.

Its works fine.
But after some time url rewrite changes the type to system and Target Path Url rewrite upgrade themselves automatically.

like

```
type = system
Target Path = catalog/category/view/id/158
```

And give messages like product not found in this category.

I am creating url rewrite using url rewrite management daily 2-3 times and deleting those automatically created.

I am searching for a permanent solution

Please help me

Answer (score 1):

I've experienced this same problem.
Magento does not support "custom url rewrites" in admin panel for many reasons.

**You have 3 options:** *Easiest to Hardest*

1. Utilize a Static block
2. RewriteEngine On. Add your exception (`.htaccess`)
3. Interpret & Modify (`index.php`)

Any other method will revert on **Reindex**

Use a *cms static block* with the same content you were displaying on the *cms page* Have category display static block only, and select desired block.